# What type of join to use here?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: `StorageTransactions` and `FutureStockUsageMaterials`.

The `StorageTransactions` table shows all the movement of the products in and out of the storage, while the `FutureStockUsageMaterials` table shows possible future movements of products in and out of the tables.

I've written the following query:

```
SELECT 
 SUM(StorageTransactions.Quantity) as CurrentStock, 
 COALESCE(FutureStockUsageMaterials.FutureStock, 0) as FutureStock,
 StorageTransactions.products_ProductId 
FROM StorageTransactions 
   LEFT JOIN FutureStockUsageMaterials 
   ON FutureStockUsageMaterials.products_ProductId = StorageTransactions.products_ProductId 
 GROUP BY StorageTransactions.products_ProductId`
```

For example, if product with the product id of `3` will be used in the future, but there is no record of it being in the older transactions, what I would like to see is a line like this:

```
CurrentStock  |  FutureStock  | products_ProductId
0             |  -325.00      | 3
```

This query works as expected, as in showing 3 columns, the first being the current stock of a product, the second being the future stock of the product, and the third being the product itself. My problem is, that when there is no entry for a given product in the `StorageTransactions` table, but in the future that product should be used, this query does not return that row, I am presuming because of my join.

How could I achieve the desired behaviour, ie. getting all the products that will be used in the future?

Comment: Please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `StorageTransactions` may have null records but `FutureStockUsageMaterials` will be always available then change `LEFT JOIN` to `RIGHT JOIN`.

If both tables may have null records, then you need to use `FULL OUTER JOIN` but unfortunately `FULL OUTER JOIN` is not supported in mysql. So we need to apply workaround:

```
SELECT 
 SUM(StorageTransactions.Quantity) as CurrentStock, 
 COALESCE(FutureStockUsageMaterials.FutureStock, 0) as FutureStock,
 StorageTransactions.products_ProductId 
FROM StorageTransactions 
   LEFT JOIN FutureStockUsageMaterials 
   ON FutureStockUsageMaterials.products_ProductId = StorageTransactions.products_ProductId 
 GROUP BY StorageTransactions.products_ProductId`
UNION 
SELECT 
 SUM(StorageTransactions.Quantity) as CurrentStock, 
 COALESCE(FutureStockUsageMaterials.FutureStock, 0) as FutureStock,
 StorageTransactions.products_ProductId 
FROM StorageTransactions 
   RIGHT JOIN FutureStockUsageMaterials 
   ON FutureStockUsageMaterials.products_ProductId = StorageTransactions.products_ProductId 
 GROUP BY StorageTransactions.products_ProductId`
```